# How to use if condition in ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

**Server Code**

```
Details['11'] = {
            'id': '11',
            'name': 'Avanish'
        };
res.render('/index',{'Message': Details});
```

**Page code**

```
        <script>
           var ERRORCONST = 'Error';
           var NORECORDS = 'No records';
        </script>

<%if(Message != undefined && Message != NORECORDS && Message != ERRORCONST ){%>
<%Message.forEach(function(key){%>
<span><%= key.id %> - <%= key.name %></span>
<%});%>
<%}%>
```

Getting error `NORECORDS is not defined`and print all code on page.
I have two error. One is how to use Multiple condition in single if statement and second is how to compare `javascript` varibale with server variable

Comment: You can't access client-side variables (like `ERRORCONST` and `NORECORDS`) in a server-side templating language (at least not with EJS). But why not define those two variables server-side as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <% var ERRORCONST = 'Error';
           var NORECORDS = 'No records'; %>
```

In `ejs template` please use constant like this.

You can not compare `ejs` variable and local script variable.